# Button on FormPanel not showing

Tags: javascript, extjs

Here is my code, i need the button is down of the filefield, but the butto doesnt appear in nowhere, whats the problem?

```
 Ext.define('Academico.view.etpPersonalizada.Edit', {
    extend: 'Sharedev.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.academico-etpPersonalizadaEdit',
    store: 'Academico.store.EtpPersonalizadas',
    model: 'Academico.model.EtpPersonalizada',
    cls: 'sharedev-overflow--visible',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'center',
    },
    initComponent: function () {

    this.items = [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            cls: 'sharedev-card',
            bodyPadding: 15,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    name: 'Período desta Etapa',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'hbox',
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'datefield',
                            name: 'pssEtpDtInicio',
                            fieldLabel: 'Início',
                            readOnly: true,
                            disabled: true
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'datefield',
                            name: 'pssEtpDtFim',
                            fieldLabel: 'Fim',
                            readOnly: true,
                            disabled: true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    cls: 'sharedev-card',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'auto',
                    },
                    width: 600,
                    name: 'Período desta Etapa',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'displayfield',
                            value: 'Observação do Coordenador',
                            cls: 'sharedev-card-title sharedev-bold',

                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'displayfield',
                            margin: '15 0 15 15',
                            style: 'opacity:0.5',
                            name: 'etpPrtObsCoord',
                            cls: 'sharedev-card-subtitle sharedev-bold',
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    name: 'panel2',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'textareafield',
                            name: 'etpPrtObsAcad',
                            padding: '0 8 0 0',
                            width: 600,
                            fieldLabel: 'Observação'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'filefield',
                            name: 'arqArquivo',
                            fieldLabel: 'Arquivo',
                            emptyText: 'Selecione um arquivo',
                            maxLength: 100,
                            minLength: 10,
                            buttonConfig: {
                                width: 103,
                                text: 'Procurar...',
                                iconCls: 'icon-search'
                            }

                        },
                        {
```

> Try to put here, nothing is show.

```
                            xype: 'button',
                            name: 'btnArquivo',
                            action: 'upload',
                            text: 'Enviar',
                            cls: 'sharedev-button sharedev-button--plain sharedev-blue',
                            width: 80,
                            height: 60,

                        }

                    ]
                }
            ],
```

> Same thing here.

```
            bbar: {
                xype: 'button',

                action: 'upload',
                text: 'Enviar',
                cls: 'sharedev-button sharedev-button--plain sharedev-blue',
                            width: 80,

            }
        }
    ]


    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

The problem is the buttons doesn't appear, no matter where i put them. I'm using extJS 4.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo,

```
xype: 'button'
```

It should be

```
xtype: 'button'
```